# How to restrict access a folder in my domain using web.config file aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

Hello Im Having a domain 
www.xxxx.com/folder/folder/default.aspx

inside the second folder im having lot of sub folders

i want to restrict access  for unauthorized user

can any one explain how to do using Web

i want to check the User name[session ] from the Cookies

if session is there need to allow access other wise deney

can any one pls help

```
   <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow users="xxxx"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
```

Now its blocking all users its not allowing for user xxxx

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The best way for doing this is setting the authentication mode to Windows. By doing this the server will use the domain accounts or the local user accounts to allow access. You just have to set the appropriate permissions to these users or to their user groups directly in this folder (by using the security tab in Windows folder properties).